# ¿Por qué no puedo escribir un map en un fichero binario?

Tags: java

Tengo que escribir un map formado por la clase Asignatura y un ArrayList de la clase Alumno en un fichero binario, pero me da error en la línea de `out.writeObject(map);` ¿Cómo podría escribirlo? Gracias de antemano.

```
public class Binario implements Serializable {

    private Map<Asignatura, List<Alumno>> map;

    public Binario() {
       map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void exportarBinario() {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ruta);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        out.writeObject(map);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberías conseguir la medalla [Informado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed) que es tan sencilla de ganar como leer el [Recorrido completo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender cómo funciona el sitio y cómo dar por respondida una pregunta, ya que tienes varias con respuestas pero no has aceptado ninguna aún. Esto es bueno para tí y la comunidad que te ha echado una mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegúrate que tus clases `Asignatura` y `Alumno` implementen la interfaz `Serializable`:

```
public class Asignatura implements Serializable {
    //definición de la clase...
}
```

Así mismo, revisa que las clases o elementos de tus clases también puedan ser serializables. Los tipos primitivos (`int`, `long`, `boolean`, `char`, etc), sus wrappers (`Integer`, `Long`, `Boolean`, etc) y algunas clases comunes en Java como `String` ya son serializables, por lo que no necesitas redefinirlas.

Comment: Sí, era eso, muchas gracias!